# Why is caret an illegal character in this regular expression?

Tags: java, regex, xslt, xpath, saxon

The environment is Java 8, Saxon 9.8 processor, XSL Stylesheet Version 3, running from Eclipse.

Given the following xslt command in the stylesheet:

```
<xsl:variable name="output" 
  select="fn:replace($inputstring, 
  '^.*exec\s+sp_prepexec.+?N'([^@](?:[^'']|'''')+)''.*$', '$1', 'ism;j')" />
```

Produces the stacktrace:

```
net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Invalid character '^' in expression
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.grumble(XPathParser.java:281)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.grumble(XPathParser.java:238)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.grumble(XPathParser.java:225)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.nextToken(XPathParser.java:196)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseDynamicFunctionCall(XPathParser.java:2358)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseStepExpression(XPathParser.java:1974)
...
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.Main.main(Main.java:72)
```

I did not find any clue why a caret won't be allowed in that expression - can you support me debugging this?
I was wondering if escaping is a problem, in the code line above I doubled single apostrophes in the expression, also tried it with ', but it is always the same error message. 
Given from the flags I assume that Saxon would use the Java regex parser for this, but the returned stack trace does not show that.

This is an example of the input string I want to process:

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=328
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 int,@P2 char(1),@P3 char(1)',N'SELECT "Tbl1009"."RUN_NO" "Col1111","Tbl1009"."DEP_ID" "Col1114" FROM "run" "Tbl1009" WHERE @P1="Tbl1009"."RUN_ID" AND ("Tbl1009"."Profile_ID"=(1) AND @P2=''N'' OR "Tbl1009"."Profile_ID"=(5) AND @P3=''Y'') AND ("Tbl1009"."Profile_ID"=(1) OR "Tbl1009"."Profile_ID"=(5))',150,'N','N'
select @p1
```

and the required output:

```
SELECT "Tbl1009"."RUN_NO" "Col1111","Tbl1009"."DEP_ID" "Col1114" FROM "run" "Tbl1009" WHERE @P1="Tbl1009"."RUN_ID" AND ("Tbl1009"."Profile_ID"=(1) AND @P2=''N'' OR "Tbl1009"."Profile_ID"=(5) AND @P3=''Y'') AND ("Tbl1009"."Profile_ID"=(1) OR "Tbl1009"."Profile_ID"=(5))
```

Comment: Although stack traces reflect internal code structure and don't really help unless you know the internal code, this particular stack trace should give you a strong clue that the complaint is from the XPath parser, not the regex parser.

Answer (score 3):

@WillBarnwell has the correct diagnosis but the wrong solution. The problem with the `'` isn't that it is special in regular expressions, the problem is that it is special in XPath, so you need to use XPath-level escaping, and the way to do that is to write it as two apostrophes. This can get pretty bewildering so the best thing is often to move the regex to a variable defined with content:

```
<xsl:variable name="regex" as="xs:string"
  >^.*exec\s+sp_prepexec.+?N'([^@](?:[^']|'')+)'.*$</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="output" 
  select="fn:replace($inputstring, $regex, '$1', 'ism;j')" />
```

(Check that carefully because I'm not sure I have fully understood your intent).

Comment: Thanks for having the domain specific knowledge :) This is definitely the answer to be accepted

Comment: But as I specified in the question, I have doubled the apostrophes. But I just see on reviewing the question, I might have missed one apostrophe here. But I came to the same solution, defining the regex as variable ahead of using it.

Comment: Precisely: you missed one of the apostrophes.

Answer (score 2):

syntax error, your regex is ending at the first unescaped single quote and is being interpreted as `^.*exec\s+sp_prepexec.+?N` this is then followed by `([^` with `^` being the first illegal character. Notice that the error is originating from the XML parser, not the regex engine.

Escaping your single quotes with `\'` is not the way to solve this, as @Michael-Kay shows it is define your regex in a variable.